# page GUI - Combobox pass variable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

New to GUI.  Not quite getting there. I used page and get can get buttons to do something (click on a button and get a response).  With `Combobox`, I can't pass a value. Searched here, tried many things, watched a few hours of youtube tutorials.

What am I doing wrong below?  This is the code page generates (basically) then I added what I think I need to do to use the `Combobox`.

I am just trying to have 1,2,3 in a combo box and print out the value that is chosen.  Once I figure that out I think I can actually make a simple GUI that passes variables I can then program what I want to do with these variables being selected.

```
class New_Toplevel_1:
    def __init__(self, top):

        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(textvariable=self.box_value)

        self.TCombobox1.place(relx=0.52, rely=0.38, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.24)
        self.TCombobox1['values']=['1','2','3']
        self.TCombobox1.configure(background="#ffff80")
        self.TCombobox1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TCombobox1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',func=select_combobox)

def select_combobox(self,top=None):
    print 'test combo ' # this prints so the bind works
    self.value_of_combo = self.ttk.Combobox.get() # this plus many other attempts does not work
```

Comment: What do you mean " On combobox, I can't pass value"? Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: Not sure how to state.  User selects 1 , 2 or 3.  My code is unable to tell what that 'value' is.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to the definitions of a class and a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what you're actually asking about, since there is more than one thing wrong with your code. Since you say the print statement is working, I'm assuming the only problem you have with your actual code is with the last line.

To get the value of the combobox, get the value of the associated variable:

```
self.value_of_combo = self.box_value.get()
```

Here's a working version where I fixed the other things that were wrong with the program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class New_Toplevel_1:
    def __init__(self, top):

        self.box_value = StringVar()
        self.TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(textvariable=self.box_value)

        self.TCombobox1.place(relx=0.52, rely=0.38, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.24)
        self.TCombobox1['values']=['1','2','3']
        self.TCombobox1.configure(background="#ffff80")
        self.TCombobox1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TCombobox1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',func=self.select_combobox)

    def select_combobox(self,top=None):
        print('test combo ') # this prints so the bind works
        self.value_of_combo = self.box_value.get()
        print(self.value_of_combo)

root = Tk()
top = New_Toplevel_1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Note: I *strongly* advise you not to start with `place`. You should try to learn `pack` and `place` first. I know `place` seems easier, but to get the most responsive and flexible GUI you should leverage the power of `pack` and `grid`.

Comment: Not sure.  the page program generated class, def__init  I added the bind statement, then (def select statement, print and get). All i want to do is select something from combo box (x,y,z,orange,apple,1,2,3 or whatever name I make up) and use it to make some decisions in code later....sigh.  I'm lost:). I'm missing something fundamental since this should be easier than what it has been. Thanks for your suggestion, didn't work directly in this code.

Comment: @jeff My answer shows you exactly how to solve your problem. I don't understand your comment. The first three paragraphs of my answer show you how to get the value of the combobox: _"To get the value of the combobox, get the value of the associated variable"_

Comment: I didn't see the code.  I can't do gui's or refresh web pages.:).  That worked, thank you so much.  I will see if I can find a good GUI tutorial.  This is just so abstract to me. Thanks again!

Comment: @jeff You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info for resources.